# ColumnChart: setting color on columnseries in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am creating *ColumnSeries* for my *ColumnChart* dynamically in ActionScript, but I can't seem to get a handle on how to set the colors on each *ColumnSeries* dynamically in ActionScript.

The *columnSeries.fill=#someCOlor* doesn't work in AS? Does anyone know how i can achieve this? The best approach would be defining an array with e.g 10 colors and then distributing them to the different columnSeries.

The code below displays how I create my *ColumnSeries*. Any help is much appriciated :)

```
            var newSeries:Array = new Array();

            var columnSeries:ColumnSeries;
            for(var i:int = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                columnSeries = new ColumnSeries();
                columnSeries.dataProvider = data;
                columnSeries.yField = DynDiagramData.valueKey +i;
                columnSeries.xField =  "genLabel";
                columnSeries.displayName = "someName";
                newSeries.push(columnSeries);                   
            }

            columnChart.series = newSeries;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 'columnSeries.setStyle( "fill", <value> );'

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the setStyle function, but it didn't do anything :-/

Comment: Instead of 'color' try 'fill'.

Comment: columnSeries.setStyle( "fill", <value> ); works. Thank you ;)

Comment: Any idea why I can't use the same approach on the LineSeries in the same chart?